# Google changes data feed urls

Tags: url, datafeed

I am submitting my data feed to Google through a service called godatafeed.com which helps me to manage and monitor my datafeeds. It adds some tracking code to the end of the url to allow me to track clicks and conversions at godatafeed.com. The issue is that at some point a number in the tracking code is changed and this means I can not track anything. I have done tests and if I pull the url from the feed file and paste it in to my browser then the click shows up. I can even login to my merchant account and go to my products and click on the link there and it is showing up as a click on my godatafeed analytics. However when I find our product in Google shopping and click on it, I go to the right page but the tracking code in the url is modified.

This is the url from the data feed file and the merchant account: 
http://www.littlegiantladder.com/type-1a-revolution.html?gdftrk=gdfV26908_a_7c497_a_7c1591_a_7c12022

This is the url from google shopping:
http://www.littlegiantladder.com/type-1a-revolution.html?gdftrk=gdfV26908_a_7c497_a_7c1635_a_7c12022

Any help to resolve would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

in you google base merchant account find the item and click on "load in debuger"

godatafeed might be generating a new number for each time it send a feed.

do you sned feeds to any other sites? if you do login to the FTP of that site and download the file godatafeed sent there and check if the number is the same as in you godatafeed  account. When godatafeed  sends a file to google, google removes the fiel right away so you cannot download it.

Also you should call godatafeed  and ask them to explain what this number is and how it is generated. The explanation might help understand what is going on.